# Magento 2.1:- To get all list of shipping carrier (Method)?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, magento-2.1, adminform

I have created admin form. I want to get shipping carrier list in admin form. How can get it? Like this below image.

[image]

Please give me proper suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods.php` class which provides a `toOptionArray()` method to provide the list of all shipping carriers.

Please note that **you can give a parameter to this method that, if set to true, will return only the active shipping carriers.**

Comment: Hello Raphael, Thanks for help. I got it, but now i use multiselect field for this field when i save this form i got error like this :- 
"Notice: Array to string conversion in /mage2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 2915Something went wrong while saving the page."
Please give me suggetion for this.

Comment: @PayalPatel feel free to create a new question and post your full code there. It's not convenient with the comments

Comment: Hello Raphael, Check my new question.